# Pressure inside when a container is closed

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, weight

Let us suppose that there is a container with its lid open sitting at the bottom of an ocean. The pressure at the bottom of the container will depend on the water column above it assuming only static pressure. Now if I close the lid of the container will the pressure at the bottom of the container reduce? I think it will because the height of the water column has been reduced. The lid supports almost all the weight of the water column above it. I know it's a stupid question but I don't know where I am wrong. Am I missing something?! [image]
Sorry for the bad drawing. P is the required pressure near the bottom of the container after closing the lid. Assume that the pressure is only due to the weight of the water column.

Comment: When you say that lid supports all the weight you forget that now that whole weight acts on the column below so the wait does not change and not the pressure.

Comment: The molecules of the water above the kid are bombarding it and the lid communicates that pressure to the water inside the container which then communicates it ti the bottom and the situation is just like the original.

Comment: Ok so the whole weight now acts on the lid so how does the pressure gets transferred inside as there are no holes are gaps.

Comment: If you keep a book on top of a table ...is the combined weight of the table and the book not increased on the floor?

Comment: The lid is not cancelling out the weight as you think.

Comment: If we neglect the bombardment by the molecules. Would the pressure still be same. If we consider only the weight of the column.

Comment: Water does not have to go inside to apply the pressure it applied that pressure on the lid...pushes it down and it being supported by sides which have a bottom touch the floor,  pushes the bottom down which comes as increased weight

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I am talking about the bottom of the container from the inside. The inside bottom.

Comment: Think of it this way : First you had a water column of mass W1 applying pressure. Now you have a water column W2 (inside the box) applying pressure  + the pressure due to the lid which is supported by the bottom (due to weight W1-W2) so net is same

Comment: How is the weight w1-w2 adds up to the weight of column inside i.e W2. The weight w1-w2 is fully supported by the lid. Isn't the situation like i am carrying 100 rice bags on my head now if i insert a lid between the 5th and 6th bag. My head will bear the weight of only 5 bags cause the weight of the remaining 95 bags will be  supported by the lid and the sides of the container. is my analogy right?

Comment: What are the sides od the container supported by?

Comment: You cannot differentiate top and below bottom here. The sides are supported by the whole of bottom. They try to bring the whole of bottom down.

Comment: The sides of the container are supported by the ocean bed. Inside the container near the bottom i don't see what adds to the weight of the column inside the container.

Comment: The part touching the ocean bed is connected to the upper part of the bottom...this is what pulls it down too

Comment: I could follow @Lost, till the second last comment. But, I don't understand the last one. Can you please let explain what you mean?

Comment: @Manish i am also confused. Doing a bit of research I found out that if we model the molecules like springs then everything works fine. Because now the molecules inside the container near the lid can push the lid from the inside causing the same pressure on either side. i think this explains it but i am not 100% sure.

Comment: Some of the force will be transferred through the cap, along the sides of the container, to the floor. What you say may be true, if the plate is placed, without any container. Since a container exists, there will be forced carried away by it. Don't you think so?

Comment: Made the picture a better fit

Comment: @shahroze shahab Hi so the explanation gave by BowlOfRed is essentially the same as mine. May I ask what was it with my explanation that made you confused which you understood in the accepted answer?  I am asking this to improve upon my amswers for future. Thanks.

Comment: @Lost you were discussing about the sides of the container which was not what i meant. Anyways your comments were helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Since the sides are connected to the base...the weight or pressure gets transmitted to the base by the sides only which are connected to the base. Like if you see your figure you will see that a force on it will get transmitted down to the base through the sides you drew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We often simplify the pressure at the bottom of a (dense) fluid to be $P = \rho g h$.  But this is only the additional pressure at the bottom due to the fluid.  If there is pressure at the top of the fluid, that is added in as well.

So the pressure at the bottom is $P_{bottom} = \rho gh + P_{top}$

When you close the lid, the column of fluid in the box is shorter, but the pressure applied to the top of the column is increased due to the rigidity of the lid. The pressure at the bottom remains unchanged.

Comment: Ok now i got it. Can the spring model for the water molecules described here (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/312119/why-does-pressure-increase-with-water-depth) explain this too?

Comment: Sure.  At the beginning the springs are compressed by the weight of the water.  When you close the lid, the lid keeps them compressed.  If you take the water off the top (lift the container out of the water), then the pressure inside remains the same due to the lid.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer.

Comment: @BowlofRed. I was thinking on the same lines as your answer but I was confused regarding something. If the lid is completely rigid and supported by the walls connected to the ocean bed then the weight gets transferred to the ocean bed and hence the pressure. How does it add to the inside bottom of the container?. Note here that I do agree that the pressure will get added but I am disagreeing on the point where it gets added.

Comment: If the container is closed, there is no path to the ocean bed, just to the other walls (including the floor).

Answer (score 1):

When you attach the lid the pressure above and below it is the same, it's in equilibrium. The pressure inside the container doesn't change when the lid is attached. Yes, the water column above the base of the container has been reduced in size but the top of that small container-sized column is at high pressure, it's not at surface pressure.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the type of lid.

For an ideally rigid lid, the weight of all the water above it will be transferred to the floor, through the container. So, the pressure at the bottom of the container will be the same as what it would have been, if the container were outside water.

For an ideally elastic lid, the pressure will completely be transferred into the container, and the pressure at the bottom of the container will be same as that outside the container, at the same depth.

For real container in between the above two cases, the pressure will be intermediate of the above two, based on how much is transferred through the lid, and how much is tranferred throught the container.

Answer (score 0):

> Now if I close the lid of the container will the pressure at the
> bottom of the container reduce?

You can think of this another way. Imagine that you are sitting at your desk and you have an empty plastic water bottle. What do you think will happen when you close the lid? If your answer is nothing then you are correct! Because if the pressure inside reduces when you close the lid, the bottle will crumple. The fact that nothing happens means that the pressure inside the bottle remained the same when you closed the lid.

The same logic applies when you do this experiment under water.